# Как поместить массивы строк в один массив?

Tags: java

Как поместить массивы строк в один массив?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] s_1 = new String[]{"1", "5"};
        String[] s_2 = new String[]{"1", "5"};
        String[] s_3 = new String[]{"1", "5"};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] ss = Stream.of(s_1, s_2, s_3)
    .flatMap(Stream::of)
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: есть ли ещё другой способ?

Comment: Наверняка есть. И не один, вероятно. Но скорее всего все другие способы будут намного более объёмны. Чем вас этот не устраивает?

Comment: использование потока данных)

Comment: Так это же хорошо.